# Why was the second line of the Battle for Winterfell comprised of catapults?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I don't really understand why they had the second line using trebuchets and catapults instead of the last line next to the wall, so they could continue to fire.

Feels like it closes down the retreat path having them close to the wall but I don't know. Maybe someone can explain?

Comment: Or inside the walls

Comment: Because the battle plans were cast aside for knighthoods, sex and karaoke.

Comment: Feels like inside would be impossible due to how Winterfell looks like, it doesn't have broad towers and the walls are narrow as well.

Comment: Maybe they didn't have much ammo after using all of their oil for the trench so they just figured they'd be an obstacle for the undead?

Comment: Can't they throw dragonglass?

Comment: The battle plans were not the most effective. Plus, from a real-world perspective, it looked cooler.

Comment: @Starseeker Trebuchet were used historically inside walls, or in top of them/top of towers. Even in ASOIAF, the tree whores were inside kings landing, protected by river/mud gate. I don't see how couldn't they do the same with winterfell, the walls are not so high and it throw projectile in a parabolic way

Comment: Inside the wall takes up space for defenders and also creates the same issue I terms of breaking up defensible formations.

Comment: I'd ask who ever said "cease fire", and then failed to call for a second volley to cover the retreat while they were being routed. These comments aren't far off; the lack of a coherent chain of command is palpable. As seen when Davos has to call to have the gate opened, and the looks he gets from either of the two people whom should have said it.

Comment: Catapults/trebuchet were basically useless in this scenario, there was no way for them to have any meaningful impact on the battle before being overwhelmed by the undead hordes - maybe they thought they'd only have time for one volley and then they'd be more useful as obstacles to hide behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a lot I found wrong with the episode but overall The tactics used here make perfect sense.

A catapult or Trebuchet has a long range but also has a minimum range due to the way it throws its payload into the air. This means that within a certain distance the enemy is safe from attack.

Catapults and trebuchets are also imprecise so once the armies clash firing would need to stop in order to prevent friendly fire.

Now if the catapults has been placed at the base of the wall behind they would have filled the space between the wall and the fire pit but would have not been able to hit the dead at all. This would have then created problems for the defenders, the unsullied defensive formation relies on them being positioned as a solid unit. You see this in the way they retreat the central soldiers fall back as the formation narrows down (this was one of the best looking scenes of the episode). if they are forced to retreat amongst fixed wooden structures such as catapults this creates small groups that can be picked off piece by piece and makes it harder to fight. Also if the artillery is near the wall it can be easily used to climb up the walls.

The only other tactic with artillary is to place it far far behind the battle but that tactic suits open battle not a defensive action where the aim is to protect a fixed position.

The tactic I don’t understand was the use of the dolthraki. I would have held them back out the way and used them once the army of the dead had reached the castle to attack the rear catching the army between the castle walls and themselves. Charging them off on there own looked great but was always a waste of soldiers.!

Comment: Best explanation I've heard for the Dothraki is that they are not disciplined medieval-style cavalry, but a superstitious group of savage raiders.  Charging the enemy and overwhelming them is what they do.  So give them some magical flaming weapons to feed their superstition, and off they go to do what they do best.  The post-credits interviews with the directors indicate that out of world this was mostly done to emphasize that everyone was pretty much boned, that killing the Night King was really the only hope, and things were not going to go as planned.

Comment: It seems a pretty solid in-world explanation to me, all said.  You'll notice that the people who had proper military training and good armor survived a lot longer.  Brienne, Jaimie, and Podrick spent seemingly half the battle shoved up against a wall by a horde of attackers and were just fine.  The Unsullied held the line and protected the retreat just fine, at least relative to how quickly the Dothraki went down.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy `Brienne, Jaimie, and Podrick spent seemingly half the battle shoved up against a wall by a horde of attackers and were just fine.` The perks of being a named character

Comment: @JAD Also the perks of having the best arms, armor, and combat training in perhaps the entire army.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy better than the Dothraki, sure. A dash of plot-armour to go with it as well.

Comment: @JAD Maybe, but most people vastly underestimate the benefits of good armor, good weapons, and combat training.  They're huge advantages.  The undead seemed like largely unskilled combatants using ancient half-broken weapons or nothing but their teeth and nails.  Good armor renders those into mostly just nuisances, whereas they're lethal to the poorly armored.  Also, don't forget that Dragonglass and Valyrian steel literally one-shot them.  Scratch them once and they're down, no second chances.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy that might be, but every unnamed character in the army, even those with armour appear to die in one hit by the wights. Everybody is completely ran over, unless they have a name.

Comment: I don’t care about your combat training if your pushed against a wall by a horde of creatures that will never flee one of them is going to stab one of you. They couldn’t swing properly because of the horde and they couldn’t get away because of the wall. The unsullied tactic was predicated on the front ranks breaking the charge like a wall. There training and discipline meant that even though the ones at the front knew they would probably die in the first attack they held fast so those behind could deal with the enemy.